# Throwing error saying that context must be a dict rather than str

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am newbie to dJango.
What I want is that passing the data from `view.py` to `.html` in order to handle the data from the models.

However, I had a hard time passing the data from `view` to `html` page. My code is as shown in below.

**form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
{% load staticfiles %}

<form method="post" action="../form/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="files" multiple/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>


<form method="post" action="../form/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for c in column_name %}
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{c}}</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="columns" value="{{c}}"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if column_name %}
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    {% endif %}
</form>

<script>
var data = {{ columns_dict|safe }};
console.log(data);
</script>
```

**views.py**

```
def Form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if len(request.FILES) !=0:
            file = request.FILES['files']
            column_name = upload_file_name(file)
            return render(request,"index/form.html",{"column_name":column_name})
        else:
            columns = request.POST.getlist('columns')
            print(columns)
            columns_dict = dict(columns)
            print(columns_dict)
            return render(request,"index/form.html",json.dumps(columns))
    else:
        return render(request,"index/form.html",{})
```

As you can see, I have been trying to pass the  data in the code below.
`return render(request,"index/form.html",json.dumps(columns))`

However, in the html page, the script block

```
<script>
var data = {{ columns_dict|safe }};
console.log(data);
</script>
```

it cannot show the data from `view.py`.
I can see the error below.
`context must be a dict rather than str.`

How to resolve my issue?

Comment: you should pass dictionary like `return render(request,"index/form.html",context = {'some key ' :  json.dumps(columns))`  .....then use this 'some key' in html

Comment: The template expects a context variable called `column_name`. Does the `columns_dict` contain that key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass data from your view in a template you must pass data in a dictionary.

```
def my_view(request):
   # statements
   return render('myhtml.html', {'data': json.dumps(data)})
```

---

[Reference](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/dynamic_data_in_templates/)